# Decode a multipart array from jQuery to PHP via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ive finally managed to get this array build and sent to my PHP function via ajax however, I dont seem to be able to decode it / var_dump produces nothing in the response panel on success.

My arrays:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    newEmailForm: newEmailForm,
    properties: properties
});
```

Which produces this:

```
 {"newEmailForm":[["coda@knoppys.co.uk","sikjdhf","Youe message here"]],"properties":[["31466","asdasd","asdads"],["31440","asdasd","asdad"]]}
```

My ajax function which is posting over the following array.

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: siteUrl,
            type:'POST',
            action: 'elegantSendEmail',
            data:data,             
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(result){

                console.log(result); //This returns nothing, not even 0

            }
        });                     
    });
```

My PHP function. If i simply echo hello world then it works.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_elegantSendEmail', 'elegantSendEmail' );

function elegantSendEmail() {

  $array = json_decode($_POST('data'), true);
  var_dump($array);
  wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not posting the data as form-encoded, so it won't be in `$_POST`. It will be sitting in the input buffer.

```
$your_json  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$your_array = json_decode($your_json, true);
```

Comment: whats php://input ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the sent data in you php code through $_POST('data') you would want to send it in the data key

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: siteUrl,
        type:'POST',
        action: 'elegantSendEmail',
        data: { data: data },             
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(result){

            console.log(result); //This returns nothing, not even 0

        }
    });
```

Comment: Response still comes back with 0